# Can mysql json_contains be case insensitive?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I want to be able to 'search' case insensitive with `json_contains`

This is the json example:

```
[
  {
    "title": "foo Bar",
    "author": "melaine"
  },
  {
    "title": "incredible",
    "author": "steve"
  }
]
```

What I tried:

```
SELECT json_contains('[{"title":"foo Bar", "authour": "melaine"}, {"title":"foo barius", "authour": "steve"}]', '{"title":"foo bar"}')
```

Expected outcome: `1`

Real outcome: `0`

Becuase I look for "foo bar" and the value in the json is "foo Bar", I do not get a match. Is there a way make this case insensitive so I do get a match?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert both the JSON (haystack) and the searching block (needle) to lowercase using [`LOWER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) function, for case-insensitive search:

```
SELECT json_contains(LOWER('[{"title":"foo Bar", "authour": "melaine"}, {"title":"foo barius", "authour": "steve"}]'), 
                     LOWER('{"title":"foo bar"}'))
```

[DB Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iRSwZzPiWTDfmyLSnmuX6Q/0)

Comment: This is way easier than I thought, thanks! One question that I still have: does this also work with the haystack being a column with rows filled with similar JSON values? Or does this only work for this small example where the haystack is just one string?

Comment: @dylanvanw You can do it like this JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(LOWER(COLUMN_NAME), '$.NODE'), LOWER('{"title":"foo bar"}'))

Comment: This is a right answer to the question, but you can't anticipate all the possibilities of cases : what about fOo baR ? There should be an answer with wider results